# Create a frequency Dictionary from the Char array

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a question concerning the C the task is to create a frequency Dictionary from the Char array, I almost did that, but the issue is that at the end, when i try to apply the words into the second array of chars. Could please give advice how to manage this issue. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

template<typename T>
int Count(T* M);
template<typename T>
T** CreationOfMatrix(T **M, T* Text);
template<typename T>
void SortUp(T**Array, int count);
template<typename T>
void Reflect(T**Array, int count);
template<typename T>
int Computing(T**Array, int count, T**NewArray,int*NewIntArray );
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char *Text=new char[100];
    strcpy_s(Text,strlen("she has a cancer and ... did anything ... she certainly did. ")+1,"she has a cancer and ... did anything ... she certainly did. ");
    //char Text[100]="she has a cancer and ... did anything ... she certainly did. ";

    char*pText=Text;
    cout<<Text;
    int count=Count(Text);
    cout<<endl<<count<<endl<<Text<<endl;
    char **Matrix= new char*[count];
    Matrix=CreationOfMatrix(Matrix, Text);
    SortUp(Matrix, count);
    Reflect(Matrix, count);
    char**NewArray=new char*[count];

    int* NewIntArray=new int[count];
    int size=Computing(Matrix, count, NewArray, NewIntArray);
    cout<<size<<"\n\n";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<NewArray[i]<<"\t"<<NewIntArray[i]<<"\n";
    }
}

template<typename T>
int Count(T* M)
{
    int i=0;
    T *temp=NULL;
    char Copy[100];
    strcpy_s(Copy,strlen(M)+1, M);
    T* S=strtok_s(Copy, ".,?:! ", &temp);
    while(S)
    {
        i++;
        S=strtok_s(NULL,", .?!",&temp);
    }
    return i;
}
template<typename T>
T** CreationOfMatrix(T **M, T* Text)
{ 
    int i=0, j=0;
    T *temp=NULL;
    T* S=strtok_s(Text, ".,?:! ", &temp);

    while(S)
    {
        cout<<S<<"\n"; 
        i=strlen(S);
        M[j]=new char[i+1];
        strcpy_s(M[j],i+1,S);
        j++;
        S=strtok_s(NULL, ".,?:! ", &temp);
    }
    return M;
}
template<typename T>
void SortUp(T**Array, int count)
{
    T temp[50]=" ";
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<count-1; j++)
        {
            strcpy_s(temp, strlen(Array[j])+1, Array[j]);
            if(strcmp(Array[j],Array[j+1])>0)
            {
                strcpy_s(Array[j], strlen(Array[j+1])+1, Array[j+1]);
                strcpy_s(Array[j+1], strlen(temp)+1, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
template<typename T>
void Reflect(T**Array, int count)
{
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<Array[i]<<endl;
    }
}

template<typename T>
int Computing(T**Array, int count, T**NewArray,int* NewIntArray )
{
    int size=0;
    int repeat=1;
    bool Flag=true;
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {Flag=true;
    repeat=1;
    for(int k=i-1; k>=0&&(Flag); k--)
    {
        if(!strcmp(Array[i], Array[k]))
            Flag=false;
    }
    if(Flag)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j<count; j++)
        {
            if(!strcmp(Array[i], Array[j]))
                repeat++;
        }
        NewIntArray[size]=repeat;
        NewArray[size]=new T[strlen(Array[size])+1];
        strcpy_s(NewArray[size],strlen(Array[size])+1,Array[size]);
        cout<<NewArray[size]<<"\t"<<NewIntArray[size]<<"\n";
        size++;
    }

    }
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Definitely not [tag:c]

Comment: I didn't understand what the program should do? Should it count the number of appearances of each letter? And what exactly is the issue that you see at the end?

Comment: At the end the programme should count the number of appearances of each word, show this words in alphabetical order and near this words show how many times these words appear.

Comment: So at the end I created 2 arrays - 1 for words and the 2nd for times of appearance of these words. Some words repate and when I try to copy the next not repeated word after the repeated one  - it for some reason pastes the repated one. I suppose that maybe I need to clean smth, but dont know exactly what to do with this.

Comment: Use map in C++ instead

Comment: for ex word did - as you can see it repates and is pated 2 times following into the second array, instead it should be ommitted.

Comment: Is there an assumption that the words are separated by a space and only one space? If yes, than it is easy to do. just read about `std::string`, `std::map` and `std::algorithm` of the standard C++ library.

Comment: I separated words, created 2 arrays, I have 1 small issue - why at the end the word did , that should be ommited pasted in ths array, so it stays somewhere in the memory , how to clean it? Dont you understand what i mean?

Comment: @LPs It doesn't look like C++ either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the following two lines of `int Computing(...)`

```
    NewArray[size]=new T[strlen(Array[size])+1];
    strcpy_s(NewArray[size],strlen(Array[size])+1,Array[size]);
```

Your index into `Array` should be `i`, not `size`:

```
    NewArray[size]=new T[strlen(Array[i])+1];
    strcpy_s(NewArray[size],strlen(Array[i])+1,Array[i]);
```

Otherwise, things start to go wrong as soon as you start skipping repeated words, when `i` is no longer equal to `size`.

As others have said, this would be so much easier with C++ data structures rather than plain arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! I spend on this issue 2 days following and couldnt get it:)
Concerning structures I looked at it, but we havent yet learned it, so thats why i am struggling with char arrays:)

Comment: I see - I'm a bit surprised that you are learning to write your own template functions before being introduced to the basic C++ data structures, but hopefully your Prof knows what they are doing. Good luck!